# Any way to limit bandwidth per IP in network behind linux router

Tags: linux, bandwidth, tc, qos

I whant to limit bandwith of clients from network behind my linux based NAT gateway.
My clints is connected via wifi or directly via ethernet to router and receiving their IP address from DHCP.
I want to limit bandwith near 3Mb per Client IP.
Now I has setup `tc qdisc` limiter for network interface and this summury bandwith limit for all clients.
How to limit per IP?
Create class and filter for each IP? Total 254 classes for network (192.168.1.0/24)
Looking like not good way...

Comment: *Why*? Isn't it more important that bandwidth is shared fairly? Unused BW is usually not something worth preserving.

Comment: This is guest network with internal rules.

Comment: Yes, but usually it's either more interesting to limit total use, or ensure fair sharing so everyone get a good expirience...

Comment: So. Any ways to make my case?